# How to make text transparent when having rest visible?

Tags: html, css

I have image as a background, and over that, a semi-transparent block. I am trying to make the text like cut out of the block, so I can see the background fully only where the text is. Any help?

I am doing it for my phone (iPhone Cydget) and the backgournd is loaded as normal lockscreen bacground. I would just like to put a div with opacity 0.5 over the background and cut out like clock within it (opacity 0 where the numbers pixels are).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<style>
#hour{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 0;
font-size: 500;
font-weight: 900;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
text-align: center;
height: 568;
width: 640;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}
#minute{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 0;
margin-top: 568;
font-size: 500;
font-weight: 900;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
text-align: center;
height: 568;
width: 640;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    function timer(){
    var Time = new Date();
    var Minutes = Time.getMinutes();
    var Hours = Time.getHours();
    Minutes = (Minutes < 10 ? "0":"") + Minutes; 
    Hours = (Hours < 10 ? "0":"") + Hours;       
    $("#hour").text(Hours);
    $("#minute").text(Minutes);
    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
    }
    timer();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
        <span id="hour"></span>
        <span id="minute"></span>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: can you post what you've tried? and maybe make a jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have something like this

```
<div id="a_div">text</div>
```

Place this `<script>` in `<head>`

```
<script>
document.getElementById("a_div").style.opacity = "0.5";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a span so you can apply a style to it in css:

**HTML**

```
<div id="bg"><span>semi-transparent text</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bg span { color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); } //black text with half transparency
```